# PHP fread() other length argument than filesize

Tags: php, fread, filesize

I am trying to have PHP read a file to the end, which works perfectly fine, except when the file is empty. Then it throws an error saying:

```
 Uncaught ValueError: fread(): Argument #2 ($length) must be greater than 0`
`strlen()`does not work in this case.
```

Is there some argument for the length like "read all that is there and if it is empty, just ignore it"? Here is the PHP:

```
$data_file_read = fopen("data.txt","r");
$alldata = fread($data_file_read,filesize("data.txt"));
fclose($data_file_read);
```

Comment: haha I run into this problem too sometimes, I find writing something in the file when creating it gets around this problem, just like a 0 or null or something along those lines will be fine. I am also curious though on what to do in this scenario when that isn't a viable option :P

Comment: What is the exact code that gives you this error? How are you calculating `$length` that is giving you a 0? What mode are you opening the file in? Are you checking with [feof](https://www.php.net/feof) before reading? (Please click [edit] and add the appropriate details to the question.)

Comment: Done that, thanks! There you have the code.

Answer (score 0):

Get the length of the file into a variable and check that for your length

```
$filename = "data.txt";
//
// Check file exists first
//
if (file_exists($filename) === true) {
   //
   // Get file length and check if it is > 0
   //
   $dataLength = filesize($filename);

   if ($dataLength > 0) {
      //
      // Finally read the data
      //
      $data_file_read = fopen($filename, "r");
      $alldata = fread($data_file_read, $dataLength);
      fclose($data_file_read);
   }
}
```